# Copying one datatable to another datatable c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I have one datatable called dt which has columns like **date ,name,subject**.
I want to copy part of this dt to another datatable dt3 using where condition.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
      cellData =(DateTime)row["date"];
      dt3 =  dt.AsEnumerable()
               .Where (rows =>rows.Field<DateTime>("date")== cellData )
               .CopyToDataTable();
}
```

I am trying this ,but its giving exception.
Please give a solution for this or else how to use by select query

Comment: please update your post with exception details.

Comment: the EXCEPTION is-Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.DateTime'. Please use a nullable type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatable **dt** may have rows which has null values for column **date**

Use nullable DateTime while comparing date

```
 dt3 = dt.AsEnumerable()
              .Where(rows => rows.Field<DateTime?>("date") == cellData )
              .CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to filter your table from each row. This is not correct and will create a datatable for every row.

If you want to filter your dataTable, you can use dt.Select() or use Linq :

```
var dateFilter = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015");
var dt3 = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("date") == dateFilter).CopyToDataTable();
```

Please provide more explanation if that's not exactly what you want to perform.

Comment: I am querying each single row because I am creating a table by the help of this date and after doing manipulation I am removing all rows from dt3,then after that again for another date I am creating a same dt3.